# Ruby get reset to the previously installed version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chruby

I have ruby 2.3.0 and 2.3.1 installed via chruby and:

```
$ cat ~/.ruby-version
ruby-2.3.1
```

But each time I open a new terminal window, it gets reset `2.3.0`.

```
$ cd my_rails_app
$ rails s
Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1
```

but

```
$ cat Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.1'
```

and for some reason:

```
$ chruby
 * ruby-2.3.0
   ruby-2.3.1
```

Therefore I alwasys have to do:

```
$ chruby    ruby-2.3.1
```

Comment: does that rails app have a .ruby-version file in it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default version of Ruby for it to load in your shell profile (e.g. .bashrc, .zshrc, etc) like so:

`chruby ruby-2.3.1`

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly but it doesn't seem like Chruby is using that file.